# ios - How to declare the javascript in ios?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm invoking the javascript in below code,it's working perfectly,then I append that javascript with HTML content,when I'm checking the URL scheme in IF condition it fails.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

    if(_data)

    {
        NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [_data release];
        _data = nil;

        NSString *jsString = @"<script type='text/javascript'>\
        window.external =\
        {\
        'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },\
        'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }\
        }\
        </script>";

        content = [jsString stringByAppendingString:content];
        [webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:_url];
    }
} 


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{

    if(_url)

    {

        if([_url isEqual:[request URL]])
        {
            return YES;
        }

        [_url release];
    }
    _url = [[request URL] retain];
    NSString* scheme = [_url scheme];

   //Here I'm checking the condition

    if([scheme isEqualToString:@"acs"])
    {
        // parse the JSON URL parameter into a dictionary
        NSDictionary* pairs = [self parsePairs:[_url absoluteString]];
        if(pairs)
        {
            WACloudAccessToken* accessToken;
            accessToken = [[WACloudAccessToken alloc] initWithDictionary:pairs];
            [WACloudAccessControlClient setToken:accessToken];

            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }

        return NO;
    }

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    return NO;

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this one ,

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.external =\
{\
'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },\
'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }\
}"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: I'm declaring like this but it's getting out of scope NSString *jsString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.external =\
   {\
   'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },\
   'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }\
   }"];
   
  content = [jsString stringByAppendingString:content];

Comment: why you are trying for append this string?

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/ that would be good understand for you

Comment: Have you seen that link Sunny